# C++ Concurrent GET requests

Tags: c++, http, concurrency, networking, get

I am writing a C++ application and would like to request several data files through a HTTP GET request simultaneously, where should I look to get started (needs to be cross-platform).

1. Run Application
2. Create a list of URLs { "http://host/file1.txt", "http://host/file2.txt", "http://host/file3.txt"}
3. Request all the URLs simultaneously and load the contents to variables (don't want disk writes). Each file has about 10kB of data.

What libraries would you recommend I use? libcurl? curlpp? boost asio? would I need to roll-my-own multi threading to request all the files simultaneously? is there a easier way?

Edit: I will need to request about 1000 GET requests simultaneously. Most likely I will do this in batches (100 at a time, and creating more connections as made one are completed).

Comment: Why do you need to request the files in parallel? If they are only 10kB large you would not experience a noticable delay unless your URL list is very large. Concurrency makes the implementation much more complex for a questionable gain.

Comment: If there's a latency of 100ms to perform each get and there are 10 files, parallel gets will finish in 100ms instead of 1000ms.

Comment: @lothar 
Yeah, the URL list is indeed pretty long (from 10-1000s at times), I kept it to 3 urls on the description for ease of explaining. The GET requests have a high Latency, but once it starts streaming it's super fast (so latency is the problem) thus my need for concurrency.

Comment: @lothar: if you request in parallel and one of them is delayed for whatever reason, then you have the rest to be getting on with. And if two of them delay for whatever reason, you only have to wait the longest delay, instead of the total. It's not unusual for an http request to block for a second or more for stupid connectivity or server-side reasons.

Comment: The complexity of parallel just needs to be justified. The question did not make it clear that the list would be very long and if the list were short I would still doubt if the increased complexity of crating threads and synchronizing the data access would be worth it. However the newly revealed information sheds a different light on the issue.
P.S. 
You may want to add the number to the question, as you most likely will need to use a thread pool unless you really want to open 1000 connections at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/).  I'm not super-familiar with it, but it does have a [multi-interface](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html) for performing multiple simultaneous HTTP operations.

Depending on what solution you go with, it's possible to do asynchronous I/O without using multithreading.  The key is to use the [`select(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) system call.  `select()` takes a set of file descriptors and tells you if any of them have data available.  If they do, you can then proceed to use `read(2)` or `recv(2)` on them without worrying about blocking.

Answer (score 2):

Web browsers often maintain a pool of worker threads to do downloads, and assign downloads to them as they become free. IIRC the HTTP RFC has something to say about how many simultaneous connections you should make to the same server at the same time: too many is rude.

If several of the requests are to the same server, and it supports keep-alive (which almost everyone does), then that may be better behaviour than spamming it with multiple simultaneous requests. The general idea is that you use one TCP/IP connection for multiple requests in series, thus saving the handshaking overhead. The practical result, in my experience of implementing Java HTTPConnection classes, is that you introduce a subtle bug to do with not always clearing the state correctly when you re-use the connection for a new request, and spend considerable time staring at logging/sniffer data ;-)

libcurl certainly supports keepalive (enabled by default, I think).

Comment: This is actually for communicating between a couple of servers in our LAN, so being rude is alright :) 

Good thinking about the reusing the connections.